# Publishing Website to Multiple Servers (.NET)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msdeploy, publishing, webdeploy

I am using Visual Studio publishing to publish the changes to my website on web server. Right now, I am pushing the changes to only one server. I hoping of publishing it to second server. How can I include two server in my publishing workflow so I don't have to publish 2 times using two publishing profiles.

Comment: you could publish from a batch file. you can publish with `msbuild.exe`

Comment: Will it push the changes only?

Comment: the UI in visual studio is ultimately just calling `msbuild.exe`, so it will have the same functionality

Comment: So, you are suggesting calling msbuild twice with two different publishing profile ?

Comment: You can also use a tool like [Octopus Deploy](https://octopusdeploy.com/) to automate the deployment proccess. But AFAIK it publishes all files each time (no incremental publishing).